# jQuery draggable and droppable accept and revert issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/pDuxe/

I have a `droppable` space with two `draggable` elements.  I have two issues:

1. If the `droppable` area already has a `draggable` item in it, if I then try and drop a second item on top, I need it to be `refused` and to revert back to its original position.
2. I can make use of the `revert: 'invalid'` code without problems, but if I place a `draggable` item into a `droppable` area and then want to move it back - it keeps reverting back to its place in the `droppable` area and not its original position.

So, how would I go about achieving those two situations?

Comment: Sorry, that answer was a failure :D
Check this ticket: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088485/how-to-revert-position-of-a-jquery-ui-draggable-based-on-condition

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have seen that ticket but have struggled to implement that within my scenario - hence asking this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is wrap your draggables in a `div` that you also make `droppable`:

```
<div id="originalposition">
    <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me to my target</p>
    </div>

    <div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
        <p>Drag me to my target</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can do something like the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
    $("#draggable2").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
    $("#originalposition").droppable({
        drop: function(event,ui) {
                 $("#droppable").removeClass("ui-state-highlight").addClass("ui-widget-header").html("<p>Drop here</p>"); 
              }
    });
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
                 $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Dropped!");
              },
        accept: function(dropElem) {
                //dropElem was the dropped element, return true or false to accept/refuse it
                return (!$(this).hasClass("ui-state-highlight") && $(dropElem).hasClass("ui-widget-content"));
                }
    });
});​
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/kxweq/1/).

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for - really appreciated the feedback and answer!