# Drag and drop on tables using Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a drag and drop feature from `table1` to `table2` and want to make sure the dropped `table2` cell is empty when the user drag `table1` itme. If the `table2` cell is empty, then I can drop it otherwise it will return to the `table1`.

```
 var dragging =null;

 td = $('.table td');

   $(td).draggable({
       cursor:'pointer',
       snap:$('td:empty')       
   })

  $(td).droppable({
        drop:function(event, ui){
         if($(this).text()=='') {  // $(this).is(':empty:) doesn't work either
             console.log('drop now!')
         }else{
            console.log('not empty') //revert 
          }
      }
  })
```

I am not sure how to revert the dragged item back to `table1` and how to detect if the dropped cell already has data.

Any helps? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show a jsfiddle of this?

Comment: You could probably do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3089432/341611

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.droppable()` has an option named `accept` which will accept a function as value.
If the function returns `true`, `$(this)` is considered a vaild drop target. Note that the `drop` function will then only be called if accept at all returns `true`.

```
$('td').droppable({
    accept: function(ev) {
        return $(this).is(':not(:empty)');
    },
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        alert('Drop successful!');

        // Do your stuff
    },
    hoverClass: 'hover'
});
```

See the following JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Xd6n/2/